# Resources for commercial use

Tags: android, graphics, resources

The resources at http://developer.android.com/design/index.html and in particular the resources at https://design.google.com/icons/index.html are freely usable by a programmer without pay nothing even for commercial use?

Comment: Under Open Source icon: ["Feel free to use, remix, and re-share the icons in your products. The icons are available under the CC-BY license. We'd love attribution in your app's "about" screen, but it's not required. The only thing we ask is that you not re-sell the icons."](https://design.google.com/icons/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes. You can find the full terms of reuse under the section "Web Site Content" here http://developer.android.com/legal.html